# Como redireccionar una url con expresiones regulares

Tags: wordpress, regex, redirección

Estoy usando el plugin redirection y quiero redireccionar de una url de categoría a una url de articulo.

De `https://www.misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/page/12/`

a Url destino: `https://www.misitio.com/razas/`

Lo que yo habia hecho era redireccionar de `https://www.misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/` a `https://www.misitio.com/razas/`

Con este último todo funciona bien salvo en el paginado, donde estoy obteniendo errores 404.

`https://www.misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/page/12/`

He estado probando:

de:  `^/perros-gatos/razas/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/$`

a:   `misitio.com/razas/`

Pero el código no me funciona.

Comment: Usa otro grupo de captura para todo lo que vaya tras la siguiente barra, es decir `^/perros-gatos/razas/([A-Za-z0-9-]*)/(.*)$`

Comment: No me funciona en el paginado.

Comment: Ah, quizás no entendí lo que pretendías. Quieres que la URL a la que rediriges reciba también todo el resto de la URL con el paginado? Entonces redirige de ` ^/perros-gatos/razas/([A-Za-z0-9-/]*)$` a `misitio.com/razas/$1`. He incluído la `/` dentro de los corchetes para que siga capturando cuando encuentre una, y el `$1` en la cadena de sustitución representa al grupo capturado.

Comment: Ahora no redirige a ningun sitio

Comment: Es difícil depurar sin más datos, pero quizás la expresión regular que estamos poniendo es demasiado complicada para lo que quieres. Probablemente `^/perros-gatos/razas/(.*)$` sea más conveniente. Igualmente tienes que redirigir a `misitio.com/razas/$1`

Comment: Derrepente es demasiado complicado. La paginación sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: No entiendo a qué te refieres con que no funciona la paginación. Entendí que lo que quieres es simplemente eliminar `perros-gatos/` de la URL ¿es correcto? Por tanto `https://www.misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/page/12/` debería llevar a `https://www.misitio.com/razas/page/12/` ¿sí? Y entonces ¿no ocurre eso? ¿Qué ocurre? ¿Te da un error 404 o te lleva a una url que no incluye la paginación? Puedes mirar con las herramientas de red qué cabecera `Location` recibes en la respuesta redirigida (código 302)?

Comment: Yo quiero que la url https://www.misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/page/12/  me lleve a la url  https://www.misitio.com/razas/  esta ultima sin paginación.  Efectivamente me sale un error 404. Al parecer esta algo complejo lo que quiero hacer.

Comment: Probaste con lo siguiente: de: `/perros-gatos/razas/` a `/razas/`?

Comment: Si quieres eliminar también la parte de paginación y no incluirla en la redirección, yo creo que de `^/perros-gatos/razas/(.*)$` a `misitio.com/razas/` debería funcionar. El `(.*)` absorbe el resto de la ruta.

Comment: Es posible que `misitio.com` utilice `.htacces` para crear un url de tipo `https://www.misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/page/12/`. En este caso es posible que el `.htaccess` no tenga una regla para este otro url:   `misitio.com/razas`.

Answer (score 2):

Si mueves de `misitio.com/perros-gatos/razas/page/12` a `misitio.com/razas`, estás perdiendo la paginación. Así que entiendo que lo que quieres es que el número de página esté oculto de alguna manera.

Si es así, no podrás usar el `.htaccess` para tal fin, ya que no puedes convertir peticiones GET en POST (mira esta [pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12009857/rewrite-http-get-request-to-post-in-apache-using-htaccess) en SO)

Una posible solución sería tener la página `misitio.com/razas` donde todos los datos/páginas se reciban vía peticiones AJAX. De esta manera, en la url de la página nunca se llegaría a ver el número de la misma. Iría como parámetro en las distintas peticiones AJAX que realices.